# Addressing the previous value

Tags: pine-script, trading, pine-script-v4

I would like to be able at present candle to use the value of the previous PH. Using the function [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIZXI.png) it would address the value of the previous bar which in this case would be the same as the present candle.

Thanks

```
ph = pivothigh(close, 50, 50)

var phe = 0.0
if ph
    phe := ph

plot(phe, "PH")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the previous values using the built-in `change` + `valuewhen` [functions](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_valuewhen) and control the depth with `occurrence` argument as in the example below: 0 - current value, 1 - previous one etc.

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")

ph = pivothigh(close, 50, 50)

var phe = 0.0
if ph
    phe := ph
    
plot(phe, "PH")

phChanged = valuewhen(change(phe) != 0, phe,  1)
plot(phChanged, color = color.red)

phChangedClose = valuewhen(change(phe) != 0, close[1],  0)
plot(phChangedClose, color = color.orange)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there any way I can get eg. the close of the candle when the switch happens? I appreciate it!

Comment: Updated my answer, `phChangedClose` variable track the close value of the switch (orange line)